# Is there any memory leak or some bugs in SQL Server CLR?

Tags: sql-server, memory-leaks, resultset, sqldatareader, sqlclr

There are my code, this method thrown exception usually when multiple thread invoke it, sometimes, it throw threadAbortException, some times throw out of memory or the memory is collect by SQL Server, and there are another class which is used to lock a List, it is stored the accessed client information, the SQL Server usually to clear it or release the CLR assembly, I don't know why. Can you help me if you have the CLR experience, thank you. My code as bellow:

```cs
private static bool QueryResultSet(string value)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        return false;
    }

    int returnValue;
    bool result;

    if (!Int32.TryParse(value, out returnValue))
    {
        return false;
    }

    result = true;
    try
    {   
        using (SqlDataReader dr = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(SqlHelper.connectionString,
            CommandType.Text,
            string.Format("SELECT {0} AS Result", returnValue)))
        {
            SqlContext.Pipe.Send(dr);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error(ex);
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to use a context connection?

Comment: Is there other code involved? You mention lots of (vague) things. Does this exact code snippet have the problems you are talking about?

Comment: Your error handling is questionable. Let the error bubble out. I'd feel uncomfortable running complex code like logging inside of sqlservr.exe. Why is that necessary? You are talking about locks as well. Are you sure you want to do threading inside your database process?

Answer (score 0):

When using `SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(conectionString...)` then by default you have memory leak. The ExecuteReader() method when using connection string instead of connection is faulted by design. It can't be used correctly since the Connection is made inside the method, not outside, therefore after using the reader you can't close the connection manually. Therefore, for start, create the connection inside using() statement, then pass it to the SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(_theConnection..) method.

Here is that same function from the ApplicationBlocks.Data source:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Execute a SqlCommand (that returns a resultset) against the database specified in the connection string 
    /// using the provided parameters.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// e.g.:  
    ///  SqlDataReader dr = ExecuteReader(connString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetOrders", new SqlParameter("@prodid", 24));
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="ConnectionString">a valid connection string for a SqlConnection</param>
    /// <param name="commandType">the CommandType (stored procedure, text, etc.)</param>
    /// <param name="commandText">the stored procedure name or T-SQL command</param>
    /// <param name="commandParameters">an array of SqlParamters used to execute the command</param>
    /// <returns>a SqlDataReader containing the resultset generated by the command</returns>
    public static SqlDataReader ExecuteReader(string ConnectionString, CommandType commandType, string commandText, params SqlParameter[] commandParameters)
    {
        //create & open a SqlConnection
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        cn.Open();

        try
        {
            //call the private overload that takes an internally owned connection in place of the connection string
            return ExecuteReader(cn, null, commandType, commandText, commandParameters,SqlConnectionOwnership.Internal);
        }
        catch
        {
            //if we fail to return the SqlDatReader, we need to close the connection ourselves
            cn.Close();
            throw;
        }
    }
```

As we can see from the exact function above, they are creating the connection inside that function, then they are creating the reader and returning it.

... The connection is never closed.

If we use this method then the connection pool will eventually overflow, since this function by default is producing leakage. Therefore, do not use this function by passing the connection string. Instead you open a connection outside the, pass it to the SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(), do stuff with the reader, close the reader and then close the connection.

See the modified code of your function:

```
private static bool QueryResultSet(string value)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        return false;
    }

    int returnValue;
    bool result;

    if (!Int32.TryParse(value, out returnValue))
    {
        return false;
    }

    result = true;
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(SqlHelper.connectionString)) 
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlDataReader dr = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(connection,
                CommandType.Text,
                string.Format("SELECT {0} AS Result", returnValue)))
            {
                SqlContext.Pipe.Send(dr);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(ex);
            result = false;
        }
        finally
        {
            // TODO: Here you can check if connection state is open before closing it
            conneciton.Close();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```